# Complexity matrix multiplication with repeated diagonal elements

Tags: matrices, algorithms, computational-complexity

Having two square matrices $n \times n$ where the values are repeated for entries which are located diagonally with respect to each other, is it possible to get a time complexity $O(n^2\log n)$?

I tried the Strassen method for this kind of matrices but I can't achieve to get that complexity, any tips?

An example of the matrices could be:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
5 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
6 & 5 & 1 & 2\\
7 & 6 & 5 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Thanks (:

Comment: Is that a square matrix ?

Comment: Yes sorry, I just edited it, thanks for pointing it

Answer (score 0):

The general purpose matrix multiplication of two $4 \times 4$ matrices requires $64$ elementary multiplications. Using [Strassen's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/578342/58610), only $49$ are required.

Due to the special diagonal structure of the matrices, $37$ multiplications are sufficient:

Matrix A:

```
a1 a2 a3 a4 
a5 a1 a2 a3 
a6 a5 a1 a2 
a7 a6 a5 a1
```

Matrix B:

```
b1 b2 b3 b4 
b5 b1 b2 b3 
b6 b5 b1 b2 
b7 b6 b5 b1
```

Products:

```
P01 = a1b1
P02 = a1b2
P03 = a1b3
P04 = a1b4
P05 = a1b5
P06 = a1b6
P07 = a1b7
P08 = a2b1
P09 = a2b2
P10 = a2b3
P11 = a2b5
P12 = a2b6
P13 = a2b7
P14 = a3b1
P15 = a3b2
P16 = a3b5
P17 = a3b6
P18 = a3b7
P19 = a4b1
P20 = a4b5
P21 = a4b6
P22 = a4b7
P23 = a5b1
P24 = a5b2
P25 = a5b3
P26 = a5b4
P27 = a5b5
P28 = a5b6
P29 = a6b1
P30 = a6b2
P31 = a6b3
P32 = a6b4
P33 = a6b5
P34 = a7b1
P35 = a7b2
P36 = a7b3
P37 = a7b4
```

Matrix product $C = A \times B$:

```
c11 =  P01                                    +P11                    +P17                +P22                                                            
c12 =      P02                    +P08                            +P16                +P21                                                                
c13 =          P03                    +P09                +P14                    +P20                                                                    
c14 =              P04                    +P10                +P15            +P19                                                                        
c21 =                  P05                        +P12                    +P18                +P23                                                        
c22 =  P01                                    +P11                    +P17                        +P24                                                    
c23 =      P02                    +P08                            +P16                                +P25                                                
c24 =          P03                    +P09                +P14                                            +P26                                            
c31 =                      P06                        +P13                                                    +P27    +P29                                
c32 =                  P05                        +P12                                        +P23                        +P30                            
c33 =  P01                                    +P11                                                +P24                        +P31                        
c34 =      P02                    +P08                                                                +P25                        +P32                    
c41 =                          P07                                                                                +P28                +P33+P34            
c42 =                      P06                                                                                +P27    +P29                    +P35        
c43 =                  P05                                                                    +P23                        +P30                    +P36    
c44 =  P01                                                                                        +P24                        +P31                    +P37
```

It might be possible to reduce this number even further.
No optimization was attempted rather than keeping track of the products which actually occur.